# How to add a list and delete a list dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `div` which contains `<ul>`. This `div` acts like a basket.
I have a `button` where it says 'add to favourite list' in which it adds something to the list. I also have a button where it says 'delete from favourite list' in which it deletes from the list.

I want to dynamically append a text inside the `<ul>` (essentially make it a `<li>`) and also delete it dynamically. For example, if the user is on a page about a resort called 'Terrific Resort' then when the user presses add, the name 'Terrific resort' should appear in the list. I used Boolean variable in my code so that it prevents the user from entering multiple times of the resort.

So far this is what I have. This is not my complete code but I can assure you that I have loaded all the scripts properly.:

```
var added = false;
var deleted = true;

$("#addToFavourites").button().click(function(event) {
    if (added == false) { 
        added = true;
        alert("You clicked on the add button");
        $("#cart").find("ul").append(erer);
    }
});

$("#deleteFromFavourites").button().click(function(event) {
    if (added == true){ 
        added = false;
        alert("You clicked on the delete button");
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <button id="addToFavourites">Add this to my favourites list!</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <button id="deleteFromFavourites">Delete this from my favourites list!</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8"> 
            <div id="cart">
                <h1 class="ui-widget-header">Favourite Resorts</h1>
                <div class="ui-widget-content">
                    <ol>
                        <li class="placeholder">Your current favourite resorts:</li>
                    </ol>
                    <ul></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a specific problem with the code you have?

Comment: Can you put together a plunker of jsfiddle?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan No there is no specific problem. the alert boxes in the in the script are used for testing purposes to see whether or not the user is able to add multiple values of the same resort. Want i want to do is to add a text to the <ul> but not sure how to do that

Comment: What text do you want to add? I can't see where `erer` is defined.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Oh that was supposed to be a string. I was seeing if the user clicked on the add button, the text erer should appear on the list

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

One thing to remember :

`$("#addToFavourites").click` binds a click event to the element with id '`addToFavourites`'. So, `$("#addToFavourites").button().click` syntax is incorrect. If you wish to target an element, if you do not wish to target with an id, then you can do : `$("input:button").click`.

```
var added = false;
var deleted = true;
var count= 0;

$("#addToFavourites").click(function(event) {
count++;
var erer = '<li class="placeholder" id' + count + '>Favourite ' + count  + '</li>';
    if (added == false) { 
        added = true;
        alert("You clicked on the add button");
        $("#cart").find("ul").append(erer);
    }
});

$("#deleteFromFavourites").click(function(event) {
    if (added == true){ 
        added = false;
        alert("You clicked on the delete button");
        $("#cart").find("ul li:last").remove();
        count--;
    }
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/9w31s3zy/

UPDATE : If you wish to add multiple items and delete them :

```
var count= 0;

$("#addToFavourites").click(function(event) {
count++;
var erer = '<li class="placeholder" id=' + count + '>Favourite ' + count  + '</li>';
        $("#cart").find("ul").append(erer);
        $(".placeholder").on("click",function(event) {
        $(this).remove();    
       });    
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/9w31s3zy/1/

Comment: Thanks for your input. I will be added other resorts in the <ul> so that delete button would'nt necesarily work as only deletes the last added resort. Would looping through the list to find a specific resort to delete be sufficient?

Comment: check the updated solution and fiddle. If you wish to add multiple items, and remove them, it would make sense to delegate a click event on each dynamically created 'li' that would delete it when you click it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be what your looking for. The thing with dynamic elements is that if your event handler is not bound to the document the element will not have an event since it didn't exist when the event was bound.

```js
$('button').click(function(){
var favourite = $('<li></li>').text(this.innerHTML);
$('#fav').append(favourite);
});
$(document).on('click','#fav li',function(){
  if(confirm("Are you sure you want to remove "+$(this).text()+" ?")){
     $(this).remove();
     }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Add me</button><button>or me</button><button>or me too</button>

<ul id="fav">
 <ul>
```

Comment: Ohh okay. I see what you did there. I'll try and do your step and let you know how it goes :)

Comment: On the second line of code, could I change 'this.innerHTML' to a string text like, ' "Terrific Resort" '?

Comment: @TarikhChouhan you can change it to anything you want I am just selecting the text from which ever button was clicked

Comment: Ok I managed to get the add part working by your method. I now need to have the delete button to delete the resort that was added by the add button. I'm thinking of traversing up the ul and loop through the ul until i find a string which matches the resorts name that the add button added. Is this efficient?

Comment: Its fine if your 100% sure you will never have a name conflict since that will create a bug. It would be better to give you li an attribute like id on creation and target it directly

Comment: after I initialise it, is it alright if I add this code?: $("favourite").append('id','TerrificResort');

Comment: if you want an attribute it would be  $("favourite").attr('id','TerrificResort') see https://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: Okay. I've got $("favourite").attr('id','TerrificResort') this code after I have initialised favourite. In my delete click function, I've wrote, $("#TerrificResort").remove(); but that doesn't seem to get rid of it from the list.